# Can ArcGIS web appbuilder work offline without Portal

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have used web app builder for ArcGIS Online. Is there a way for it to work offline without Portal? Consuming ArcGIS Server REST API

Comment: One guy done it.
Look at this. I will try it.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/chaomashi/stemapp)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation page here](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm) states:

> To use Web AppBuilder, you must have an ArcGIS organizational account
>   or an ArcGIS for Developers account. .... If you don't have an ArcGIS
>   account, sign up for an [ArcGIS free trial](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisonline/evaluate) or the [ArcGIS
>   Developer Program](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/sign-up/).